# JS - carousel | Carousel Three D

Tags: javascript, carousel

I want to use a carousel script to my portofolio.
 
(http://www.ajaxline.com/best-jquery-carousels-plugins) name: 'Carousel Three D' 
I fount the best script for me, but I can't download it. Everywhere is 404 Error. Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

I too got the 404, so I went directly to http://brainacle.com and searched through the blog articles until I found a link to carousel three d plugin:

http://brainacle.com/jqcarousel-three-d.html

There is a link to download it on that page:

http://brainacle.com/static/uploads/jqcarousel3d/Carousel3D3.js